# List pages on the frontpage view in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, hyperlink, frontpage

So, I'm relatively new to Drupal, and I'd like to make a Drupal site with a front page with a grid of links to other commonly used pages on the site. This site is intended as a sort of community page for a small town, so it would be links like Government, News, Business Directory, History, Forum, etc.

Some of these pages are basic pages on my Drupal site, some are external links, and some are links to views or modules, like the aggregator module. I'd like all of the links to be sortable and generally have the same markup. I'd also like these links to be gathered automatically, i.e. via the 'Promote to Front Page' option or something like that. I ABSOLUTELY DO NOT want to hardcode this to a basic page.

So far my solution has been to create a view with a list of title fields from pages promoted to the front page, and a special content type I named 'Link' which are actually just redirects to external urls. The problem now is that I don't know how to include special pages, like aggregator or view.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to do this? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is as follows.

1. Create a content type called link with a [link field](http://drupal.org/project/link) on it.
2. Create a page view that displays all content of type link and displays the field link

This is a very basic way of doing it, if you wanted more than one list on the page then that would depend on the theme you are using and the links would need to be categorized in someway using taxonomy.

You may also want to look at the [flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag).